# Java - enum with static counter

Tags: java, android, enums, jvm

I want to implement C++ like enums in Java, so I want to use static field as a counter. This is my current solution:

```
public enum ETest
{
    Test1(2),
    Test2,
    Test3,
    Test4(7),
    Test5;

    private static class CounterHolder
    {
        private static int mCount = 0;
    }

    ETest()
    {
        mValue = CounterHolder.mCount;
        CounterHolder.mCount++;
    }

    ETest(int pValue)
    {
        CounterHolder.mCount = pValue;
        mValue = CounterHolder.mCount;
        CounterHolder.mCount++;
    }

    public int toInt()
    {
        return mValue;
    }

    private final int mValue;
}
```

From the above code I should get:
Test1.toInt() -> 2, Test2.toInt() -> 3, Test3.toInt() -> 4, Test4.toInt() -> 7, Test5.toInt() -> 8

This code works fine with tested Android Java VM, however I'm not sure if it's a valid Java code and if it will works properly on all valid Java's VM, because AFAIK enum is initialized before static fields, however it looks like initialization on demand for nested classes with static field works fine in this case (without nested class, simple static field doesn't work).

Best regards,
Patryk

Comment: Don't try to translate C++ structures to Java. Java enums way to powerful to be abused as simple C++ style value containers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that THAT code won't compile - please use real code in questions...

Comment: @GyroGearless Well, this code compiles, because I used initialization on demand, I'm just not sure if it will not cause problems at run-time on other JVM.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle But I just need this powerful enums to work as simple value containers from C++, nothing more, so if this type is really that powerfull as you said I should be able to achieve that, but we'll see.

Comment: @PatrykNadrowski *"But I just need this powerful enums to work as simple value containers from C++"* I think what you mean is: *I wanna stick to what C++ coders believe OOP is...* ;o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CounterHolder` will always be loaded and initialised before `ETest` is initialised so your code should work as expected on all compliant JVMs. You can read more about class initialisation in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4) (not sure what the equivalent document is for android but I would expect that they have a very similar wording). In particular:

> A class or interface type `T` will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - [...]
> - A static field declared by `T` is used and the field is not a constant variable.

So at the latest, the `CounterHolder` class will be loaded and initialised before the first constructor of `ETest` runs.

Note however that from a style perspective, it would probably be cleaner to just write:

```
enum ETest {
    Test1(2),
    Test2(3),
    Test3(4),
    Test4(7),
    Test5(8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do that easily using a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) inside the enum like so

```
public enum TestEnum {
    Test1(2),
    Test2,
    Test3,
    Test4(7),
    Test5;

    private static Map<TestEnum, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        int counter = 0;
        for (TestEnum enun : TestEnum.values()) {

            counter = Math.max(counter, enun.value);
            if (enun.value == 0) {
                counter++;
            }
            map.put(enun, counter);
        }
    }

    private int value;

    TestEnum() {
        value = 0;
    }

    TestEnum(int pValue) {
        value = pValue;
    }

    public int toInt() {
        return map.get(this);
    }
}
```

and here is the function to print the results

```
for (TestEnum anEnum : TestEnum.values()) {
    System.out.println(anEnum.name() +" = "+ String.valueOf(anEnum.toInt()));
}
```

and the output is:

```
Test1 = 2
Test2 = 3
Test3 = 4
Test4 = 7
Test5 = 8
```

> **TIP:** Check something called [ordinal](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/enum_ordinal.htm), it's an ordinal of the enumeration constant (its position in its enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of zero).

Comment: Thanks, however I don't want an overhead related to HashMap to this kind of simple task.

Comment: Well, there’s `EnumMap`, exactly to avoid the “overhead related to HashMap”, when the key type is an `enum` type. Of course, since `value` isn’t `final`, the static initializer could just overwrite the zero values instead of filling a map, and `toInt` can work as before…

Answer (score 0):

In android , the best practice is avoid to use Enum for the principal reason is anti-optimise performance , based on android documentation :

> Enums often require more than twice as much memory as static
>   constants. You should strictly avoid using enums on Android.

In other side android purpose the solution the type def annotation :

> The @IntDef annotation lets you basically create a "typedef", where
>   you create another annotation which represents the valid integer
>   constants that you expect, and then you decorate your API with this
>   typedef annotation.

Here is a sample example , how to use it (checker of days ...) :
https://noobcoderblog.wordpress.com/2015/04/12/java-enum-and-android-intdefstringdef-annotation/

And for more knowing features you can read the official documentation :
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html#enum-annotations